# Add rows until today's date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

So i have this kind of R data frame, with only one obs :

| date | company |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-18 | Apple |

**Desired output**

I'd like to add rows until today's date :

| date | company |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-18 | Apple |
| 2017-08-19 | Apple |
| 2017-08-20 | Apple |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 2021-05-26 | Apple |

So that every time the code is launched, it's completed with the actual date. Is it possible ? And if yes, is it possible to automate this as a function so that i can apply it to all of my datasets with this form with a few lines of code only ?

**UPDATE**

How to do the same when there is more than one date in the data frame, such as :

| date | comapny |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-24 | AMZ |
| 2021-05-25 | AMZ |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a `seq`uence of dates by specifying the `from`, `to`, and `by` in `seq`, and wrap with `data.frame` and the 'company' column extracted from the data (as it is already specified a single row - it gets recycled)

```
date <- seq(as.Date(df1$date), Sys.Date(), by = '1 day')
data.frame(date, company = df1$company)
```

---

If there are more than one row, an option is to either use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(date = list(seq(date, Sys.Date(), by = '1 day'))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   unnest(date)
```

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(date = map(as.Date(date), ~ seq(.x, Sys.Date(), by = '1 day'))) %>%
    unnest(date)
```

---

Or may also use `complete`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(company) %>%
   complete(date = seq(min(as.Date(date)), Sys.Date(), by = '1 day'))
```

Comment: sorry i wasn't aware of that. I update my question, is it possible for you to take a look at it ?

Comment: @theeconomista I assume that each date to be expanded to today's date